# ArrayList sorting using collection

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, collections

I know that we use comparable function for sorting ArrayList of objects to sort according to a certain property of objects.
But i always wonder when we call sort directly on ArrayList of objects for example: `Collections.sort(arraylist);`
It gives error that you cant sort but actually when you print a object for example:

```
Instances in1=new Instances();
ArrayList  al=new ArrayList();
al.add(in1);
System.out.println(al.get(0));
```

You get output:

> Instances@45a8123b

which is the id of a object.

So, if we call sorting on an ArrayList then it can sort objects according to id. **So, why we get errors while sorting ArrayList of objects ?**

Comment: Why would you want to sort objects based on `hashCode`?

Comment: sorting based on this `id`, actually it is hashcode, does not make any sense, why would people implement it?

Comment: @Lashane u are right i was just asking that by default u can have that option.For example if u want tp print student name according to the date of entry then u can print object. Its a vague example but something like this.

Comment: @ArjunChaudhary With Java 8 you can do things like that really easily. E.g. `students.sort(Comparator.comparing(Student::getDate));`.

Answer (score 3):

If you want your objects to be sortable without supplying a comparator, define a natural ordering by implementing `Comparable` interface:

```
class Instances implements Comparable<Instances> {

    ....

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Instances other) {
        return Integer.compare(
                System.identityHashCode(this), 
                System.identityHashCode(other)
        );
    }
}
```

And now `ArrayList<Instances>` can be sorted by identity hashcode (however ridiculous it is to actually do that).

This way you actually have to make a deliberate effort for this to happen.  `Collections.sort` is right to not assume a behavior that's likely wrong.  If you didn't implement `Comparable` and didn't supply a `Comparator`, it is much better to error out than to just silently sort your list in semi-random order.